# Why does NSMutableAttributedString ignore the background color attribute in certain cases?

Tags: ios, background-color, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm running into a frustrating problem. I want a label to display a text string with portions of the string having different background colors.

This code works:

```
let s = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "test me bar", attributes: [:])
s.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(),
   range: NSMakeRange(4, 2))
s.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(), 
   range: NSMakeRange(8, 2))

self.detailDescriptionLabel.attributedText = s
```

[image]

But if I remove exactly one of those calls to `addAttribute` (doesn't matter which) so that I'm specifying exactly one range of the string to have a background color attribute, then no background color is displayed anywhere in the string.

[image]

I'm on iOS 8.1, and this happens in the simulator and on my iPhone 6. I found this issue in my code and reproduced it using only the above snippet in an empty project.

Any ideas? I'm pulling my hair out here. This is a stripped-down version of the problem, but it's important to my project to be able to have strings where only one region has a background color.

**EDIT** If I set one of the background colors to `UIColor.clearColor()`, then all works as expected. Am I perhaps looking at a bug in UIKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to apply `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` in whole of the text with a transparent color.

```
[s addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:(NSRange){0, s.length}];
```

Then you can apply the second color with range of the text you want to highlight.

```
[s addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:(NSRange){0, 2}];
```

**For Swift** :

```
mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.clear , range: {0, 2})

mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.yellow , range: {0, 2})
```

Comment: Yes, in my edit, I did something similar to get this to work. Do you know why this is needed?

Comment: I think this is a bug in iOS SDK, because i saw similar questions on the internet when I first ran into this problem years ago, and I had to do this to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This also Your bug :

Just do this :

```
self.detailDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 2; // <---
```

And your problem solved.

Comment: Okay, I tried again using code rather than the storyboard editor and that worked. Do you know why this change is necessary?

Comment: Actually, I find this solution during R&D.